# WPF datagrid : how to sort a column programatically?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

How do I sort a column programatically ?

I would like to have a function such as

myWPFDataGrid.Columns[0].Sort(..)

MadSeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ICollectionView` as your ItemsSource and `CollectionViewSource` to generate it. You can set the sort descriptions there and it'll sort your items for you.

Comment: You don't really need to use it as the ItemsSource. By getting the default collection view, WPF will automatically pick up the sorts you add to it.